# When a G-Suite form is embedded on external website, does any form data get stored on the host site?

Tags: wordpress, embed, google-workspace, websecurity, hipaa

This question comes up because of very specific HIPAA requirements. A Covered Entity(CE) eg, doctor can't use a [cloud storage provider (CSP) unless they have a Business Associate Agreement](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/2075/may-a-hipaa-covered-entity-or-business-associate-use-cloud-service-to-store-or-process-ephi/index.html) (BAA) with the CSP, [even if the data are encrypted and the CSP has no access.](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/2077/can-a-csp-be-considered-to-be-a-conduit-like-the-postal-service-and-therefore-not-a-business%20associate-that-must-comply-with-the-hipaa-rules/index.html) I'm not a security expert, but most web hosts' security would IMO satisfy HIPAA, **IF** there were a BAA.

There's a [conduit exception for video, ISPs, and other electronic equivalents of USPS that do not store electronic Protected Health Information (e-PHI.)](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/245/are-entities-business-associates/index.html)

I don't know why, but the web hosts who **will** sign a BAA charge $100-300/ mo for very basic hosting  other sites charge $5-15/mo for. I think they're preying on CE ignorance with the perception there's lots of money sloshing around, true for radiology, but not for primary care.

G-Suite **will** execute a BAA, which makes G-Suite a reasonably-priced solution for gathering Protected Health Information (PHI) patient input, while keeping the CE compliant with HIPAA.
It's worth noting that ["HIPAA compliance"](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/privacy/guidance/be-aware-misleading-marketing-claims/index.html) is ONLY a property of CEs and Electronic Medical Records, not other software or sites. Any other product or service claiming "HIPAA compliance" is misrepresenting itself.

I find Google Sites not as user-friendly as most web hosts. There's less hand-holding for doing things like installing WP add-ins, or adding SSL certificates.  Or maybe Google just does a terrible job of explaining how to actually DO something with a site hosted there. In any case, it seems easier to run a website on a web host that's set up to manage software and WP plug-ins for amateurs.
I'm willing to be educated on this. *(24 hours later--I did a lot of self-education-see answer below.)*

[The basic HIPAA privacy requirements are rather simple:](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/189/what-does-the-hipaa-privacy-rule-require-the-average-provider-to-do/index.html)

- CEs can use PHI to treat and carry out essential functions, but must
  not share it with anyone not entitled to it.

[The basic HIPAA security requirements are also simple:](https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/smallprovider.pdf?language=es)

1. Make a security risk analysis.
2. Implement reasonable security measures and
3. Document why various measures were taken or not.

Some elements are [required, others must simply be addressed, evaluated and documented.](https://www.hhs.gov/sites/default/files/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/security101.pdf?language=es)

For example, 2FA is "addressable" as is data encryption, but making an analysis, having physical security and employee training are required.

**So my question is whether a G-Suite form embedded in a website on another web host stores *any* data on that web host, or does it all go back to G-Suite, eg G-Drive, where it's secure and covered by a BAA?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem when you know very little about a topic is, you don't know what to ask. I know a bunch about HIPAA, not much about HTML. I did a lot more research, and there's at least two answers.

**The short answer is, NO, the embedded frame is an iframe HTTPS linked to G-Suite.
The form in the iframe is a window into docs.google.com, so data never gets off docs.google.com, where it's covered by G-Suite's BAA.** The host site is in effect a conduit.

```
 <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms......…</iframe>
```

Note **https**

Embedding the form does not create a HIPAA violation.

**The second answer is, G-Suite has its own content management system and website builder, which requires very little technical skill.** Thus there's no need to install Wordpress or anything else, you just drag-and-drop to create a site. All the back end stuff is done for you. Duh. **And they execute a BAA, all for $6 a month**. So G-Suite is much simpler, in fact so simple that only a child can do it. Their help pages leave much to be desired.

**Bottom line--for small covered entities, G Suite is a very economical website solution that doesn't create a HIPAA violation.** Wish I knew this yesterday!

FYI: [HIPAA compliant Cloud Services](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/faq/2078/which-csps-offer-hipaa-compliant-cloud-services/index.html)